# Remove section numbers latex

Tags: latex, sections

I have a problem with section numbering in latex. I want to remove the section numbers from headings and contents but I want the numbers to be there for lemmas, theorems etc. I want it to look like:

```
 Section Whatever
   Some unimportant text.

 Section Whatever else
   Another unimportant text.
   Lemma 2.1
   Theorem 2.2 

 Section Whatever again
   Theorem 3.1
```

How can I do it? I tried

```
 \renewcommand\thesection{}
```

but it removes the numbers even from lemmas and theorems. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 22):

Under the default `article` class we can merely remove the formatting applied to the section counter by adding

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{}
\makeatother
```

to the preamble. This will remove *all* sectional title numbering (`\section`s, `\subsection`s, `\subsubsection`s, ...), yet keep them where they are references or whenever `\thesection` is used.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]% Theorems numbered by section
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}% Lemma uses theorem's counter

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Section whatever}
Some uninportant text.

\section{Section whatever else}
Another uninportant text.

\begin{lemma}
Some lemma.
\end{lemma}

\begin{theorem}
Some theorem.
\end{theorem}

\section{Section whatever again}
\begin{theorem}
Another theorem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello :) That command removed the numbers from titles but they are still there in table of content. How can I fix that?

Comment: @Katarina: You can add `\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{}` to your preamble, which will remove all section numbering from the ToC.